# I want to say that something is "expensive" in terms of time and resources

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, phrase-requests

I'm  writing an academic article (physics) and I want to say that a procedure is necessary but very expensive (in terms of resources like time, infrastructure, ...) Can I say:

> Since A is *sacred* we introduce alternative B in situation C.

Or is the word *sacred* only used in a theological sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use *sacred* to mean that it uses a lot of time and infrastructure. Other than simply using *expensive*, you could also use *costly*.

Comment: Since A is 'costly in time and resource'...

Comment: I can't see any reason to prefer *costly* over OP's original *expensive*. They're both exactly the same figurative usage, and are both susceptible to being misinterpreted as only "pricey" in ***financial*** terms. *Difficult* or *demanding* might shift the focus away from "money-based" costs.

Answer (score 0):

While A) may be preferred, B) and C) also offer advantages.

*Sacred* implies the metaphysical, and in physics/math/tech arenas the literal is seen as more accurate and trusted. As an additional reference, the Kiersey Inventory studies indicate that many who trust the visible and factual over invisible may be your readers, and they may bristle at use of the term Sacred.

Personally, I prefer humor, especially to achieve leaps in logic.